# SetItem method in JS

Tags: javascript, json, methods

Recently I've been building todolist with javascript using localstorage. So idea was simple to store the lists in localstorage using number as key and listItem as value. When I tried to save a listItem the key was fine but value was the same as key it was number. Only when I appended "list" string to the key value everything started to work fine. So the question is why did it happen? [Why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQiak.jpg)?

Here is the code example:

**DID NOT WORK (THE VALUE OF INPUT WAS NUMBER EQUAL TO THE KEY):**

```
let key = Object.keys(localStorage);
key.length === 0 ? key = 1 : key = key.length + 1;

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const inputValue = document.querySelector(".textarea").value;
    localStorage.setItem(key, inputValue);
    location.reload();
});
```

**DID WORK:**

```
let key = Object.keys(localStorage);
key.length === 0 ? key = "list1" : key = "list" + (key.length + 1);

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const inputValue = document.querySelector(".textarea").value;
    localStorage.setItem(key, inputValue);
    location.reload();
});
```

P.S. I'm sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, the key parameter of `localStorage.SetItem` [should be a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem).

You can use the first solution if your replace line 6 with:

```js
localStorage.setItem(key.toString(), inputValue);
```

Also, I suggest you don't change your variables in the parts of your ternary expression. 
You should replace line 1 with:

```js
key = key.length === 0 ? 1 : key.length + 1;
```

But actually, you don't even need a ternary, you can replace it with

```js
key = key.length + 1;
```

Another suggestion, you should evaluate "key" inside the event. So the whole code would look like this:

```js
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const key = Object.keys(localStorage).length
    const inputValue = document.querySelector(".textarea").value;
    localStorage.setItem(key, inputValue);
    location.reload();
});
```